# Custom Post type page content (archive page)

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have website with multiple Custom post types and I need to create an Archive page for each post type that also has extra content (short description and the like). The way I would about this would be to create a normal Page, edit the template for that page to include the loop of posts and add the extra content/custom fields to that page. But that brings me to two issues:

- What happens if I name the page the same name the Custom post type has? for example: "Services". Will my url http://mypage.local/services point to the page or to the custom post "Services" archive?
- Even if I name it something different I will have 2 different urls that have the list of the posts, one is the archive and the other is the page, that doesn't look great to me, right?

What would be the best way to approach this?

EDIT: This is my custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'inspirer',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Inspirer Posts' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Inspirer Post' )
        ),
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'inspirer'),
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,

    )
);
```

Comment: What are your `rewrite` rules where you create post types? Show us the code.

Comment: Done and edited @MaxYudin